# Installed gem not showing in gem list

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, jruby

I am confused about adding gems. I listed the gems that are installed:

```
mypath$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
cassandra-driver (2.1.3 java)
cql-rb (2.0.4)
domain_name (0.5.23)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
httpclient (2.6.0.1)
imagesize (0.1.1)
ione (1.2.0)
jruby-openssl (0.9.7 java, 0.9.6 java)
json (1.8.2 java)
mime-types (2.4.3)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (2.9.2)
netrc (0.10.2)
rest-client (1.8.0, 1.7.2)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.5.rc10 java, 0.10.4 java)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.24)
soap4r (1.5.8)
unf (0.1.4 java)
xml-simple (1.1.5)
mypath$
```

I wanted to add the minitest-junit gem to the installed gems so I installed it and it said that the gem installation was successful.

```
myPath$sudo gem install minitest-junit
Successfully installed minitest-junit-0.2.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for minitest-junit-0.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for minitest-junit-0.2.0...
mypath$
```

When I tried to use it I got errors that the gem not known, so I ran `gem list` command again and the gem was not listed:

```
mypath$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
cassandra-driver (2.1.3 java)
cql-rb (2.0.4)
domain_name (0.5.23)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
httpclient (2.6.0.1)
imagesize (0.1.1)
ione (1.2.0)
jruby-openssl (0.9.7 java, 0.9.6 java)
json (1.8.2 java)
mime-types (2.4.3)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (2.9.2)
netrc (0.10.2)
rest-client (1.8.0, 1.7.2)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.5.rc10 java, 0.10.4 java)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.24)
soap4r (1.5.8)
unf (0.1.4 java)
xml-simple (1.1.5)
mypath$
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't there be an error if the gem does not install?

Comment: Where and how are you trying to use the gem?

Comment: if you call ruby script.rb --help you should get the minitest-junit options which show that the gem installed according to this - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest-junit/0.2.0#Usage

Comment: Can you show the script?

Comment: theres nothing really to show in the script. Its a Minitest unit test that runs as expected. I just need the results to be output in a junit format so it can be used in jenkins or bamboo. Bamboo has a junit parser that shows the tests as failed or passed. Without going through a parser the tests can not show in bamboo